# How to remove "0" from numbers of paragraphs when they are not in subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to have numbered paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{para}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\section{Lorum ipsum}
\subsection{Lorum ipsum}
\paragraph{} Lorum ipsum

\end{document}
```

However, I do get an unnecessary "0" in numbering - so the paragraph in the example is 1.1.0.1. How can I avoid this?

Comment: What if you have subsubsection?

Comment: It would be 1.1.1.1. But I want to have paragraphs of form 1.1.X.

Comment: Will `\paragraph` directives ever occur at the `section` level, i.e., without intermediating `subsection` *and* `subsubsection` levels? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Not in my case.

Comment: Can it happen in your case that there are both subsubsections and paragraphs at subsection-level? (If that can happen, different items of sectioning (subsubsections and paragraphs) might get the same number.)

Comment: How about s.th. like: `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\csname thesub\ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0 \else sub\fi section\endcsname.\arabic{paragraph}}` ?

Comment: If `\paragraph` can occur in different sectioning-levels, you probably misuse `\paragraph` and should use a theorem-like environment or the like instead?

Comment: In my case I create a spec-like document (think C++ spec) which just have sections and subsections. Creating subsubsection for 1-2 lines of text seems strange.

Comment: Redefine subsubsection so that it uses an inline style. Then you don't have to misuse paragraph.

Comment: (Just in case you're not aware of this, in which case the responses here may be puzzling:) recall that `\paragraph` does not mean ‘paragraph’! It's part of the sectioning hierarchy, and should really be thought of as an odd way to spell `\subsubsubsection`.

Answer (score 6):

The code given below does what the OP wants.

I can't help but remark that it's decidedly poor and sloppy typographic practice to skip subsubsection-level headers when also using paragraph-level headers. There has got to be a way to create a dummy-type subsubsection-level header, no?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % default: 3

% Suppress value of subsubsection counter if equal to 0:
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{%
   \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0 \thesubsection.\arabic{paragraph}
   \else \thesubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}
   \fi}
  
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
 
\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\subsection{Lorem ipsum}
%\subsubsection{Lorem ipsum} % commented out
\paragraph{Lorem ipsum} 
\lipsum[1][1-3] % filler text

\section{Nam dui}
\subsection{Nam dui}
\subsubsection{Nam dui} % *not* commented out
\paragraph{Nam dui} 
\lipsum[2][1-3] % more filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: A possible simplification would be `\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\ifnum\value{\subsubsection}>0 .\arabic{subsubsection}\fi}`

Comment: @egreg - If I replace `\value{\subsubsection}` with `\value{subsubsection}`, your suggestion works perfectly. :-)

Comment: "I can't help but remark that it's decidedly poor and sloppy typographic practice to skip subsubsection-level headers when also using paragraph-level headers" - In my case I don't have subsubsection headers or paragraph headers - just paragraph numbering. Think about it as C/C++ spec with 2 levels of sections.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka - In that case, you may want to take Ulrich Diez's earlier suggestion to heart, *viz.*, "you ... should use a theorem-like environment". C/C++ specs would indeed seem to be good candidates for Ulrich's suggestion.

Comment: @Mico Never trust code written on the phone 

Answer (score 1):

A modification to [Mico’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691779/4427), needed for a couple of reasons:

1. this is simpler code and more easily customizable;
2. you seem to use `\paragraph` with empty argument, so we need to fix the spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % default: 3

% Suppress value of subsubsection counter if equal to 0:
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{%
  \thesubsection
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}>0
    .\arabic{subsubsection}%
  \fi
}

\makeatletter
% by default, the fifth argument is -1em, but you don't want this amount
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}% level name
    {4}% level number
    {\z@}% indentation
    {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}% space before
    {-1sp}% space after (negative for inline)
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% formatting
}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}

\section{A first section title}
\subsection{This has no third level sections}
\paragraph{} \lipsum[1][1-3]

\section{A second section title}
\subsection{This has a third level section}
\subsubsection{Whatever you want}
\paragraph{} \lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change the code into

```
% Suppress value of subsubsection counter if equal to 0
% and make subsubsections letter numbered
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{%
  \thesubsection
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}>0
    .\alph{subsubsection}%
  \fi
}
```

you'd get something that would help in distinguishing the levels.

[image]